# How do I move a site to a new server?

Tags: backups

How do I move a site to a new server?

I have a backup file for the database content and all the files. I uploaded it using cPanel to the new server, imported the database, and updated the username and password as well.

For some reason, the website is just showing this message.

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

The content of the error log provided by my hosting provider is the following.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: This too broad a question to answer here succinctly for any D8 site. You'll need to consult your PHP/web server logs to understand why the above error happened.

Comment: Hi @ShawnConn I have updated my question with the error log provided by my host provider. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you may forgot to move the *vendor* directory to the new location. Also you may need to run `composer dump-autoload` to update the autoloader with your new vendor's path. Though may be obvious to many, you need to clear the Drupal cache, in this case I prefer do a truncate over the cache bins (assuming you're using the default cache backend).

**Update**

Also worth checking the *autoload.php* file in your Drupal root, this file includes the actual autoloader generated by Composer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please help with any tutorial/article which could help me to do this? I am a newbie in Drupal.

Comment: I could improve my answer with some basic or common examples